# Forge Viewer in Power BI

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360

I am trying to create a Clash/Issue Report in Power BI. Below resource shows how to embed a forge viewer in PowerBI.
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/embed-forge-viewer-inside-power-bi-report

I was wondering how can I represent the clash points in the 3D viewer if I extract the clash data from BIM 360 Insights Data Connector. Any suggestion to present those colorful clash points onto the 3D viewer visual.

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/bim-360/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Generate-Power-BI-report-of-BIM-360-project-activities.html

[3D Viewer with Clash Points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/malL4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks a few questions here:

**...extract the clash data from BIM 360 Insights Data Connector**

Data Connector does NOT provide clash data. Currently it is Model Coordination API can provide the data

**represent the clash points in Forge Viewer**
If it is a clash issue, which means it is also a general issue with 3D pushpin.  you can get the data of the 3D pushpin and present them in Forge Viewer by BIM360Pushpin issue extension. This is a sample:
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bim360-clashissue
Note: The position of the issue is same thing of the clash point.

If it is a common clash data (no associated with issue), unfortunately, Model Coordination API only tells the clashed elements, ids and the clash distance. Technically, inside Forge Viewer, you could calculate a relatively estimation of the clash point (by checking the intersection of the bounding-box of the clashed elements), but it is out of Forge APIs. Currently, the only possible presentation is like I did in this sample, i.e. highlight the clashed elements in different colors.
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bim360-clashview
Of course, you could place a pushpin (like clash issue above) by a position  (e.g. bounding-box center of one element).

**About one link you enclosed**
This link you enclosed is produce Power BI report by the data from Data Connector. As said at the beginning, Data Connector does not provide clash data yet. And that Power BI template does not have Forge Viewer imbedded.  https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/bim-360/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Generate-Power-BI-report-of-BIM-360-project-activities.html

Comment: Thanks for the help. So, how can I get this clash Forge viewer embedded to Power BI because I also need to see other metrics and visuals - disciplines, clash status etc for the project. If not from Data Connector, we can get the clash report data from Navisworks.

Comment: there is not the thing that is called [clash Forge Viewer] :)   Only [Forge Viewer]. To embed it to Power BI report, the first link you mentioned is exactly the reference. As to present clash point, as said in my reply: either highlight elements without tag(pushpin) point, or you may borrow the extension of BIM360PushpinExtension to present the clash point

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm fairly new to programming -- came from Dynamo/python background. Would it be possible to do it in .NET Core without having to learn node.js or JavaScript? Could you suggest to me a learning path to achieve this?

Comment: sorry for my late response.  To work with Viewer in client side (browser), Javascript is a must. As to backend (server side), ,NET is fine. A web application is comprised of backend + client side. Since you want to work with Forge Viewer, the best tutorial  is https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/, by which you could check other materials of Javascript when you have no idea what does it mean with the demo code.  It could help you to get started with JavaScript easily.